# Different meaning of present perfect for "have had"and "have been"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

In a previous question I asked about the meaning of "I have had cancer" (without a duration), meaning I have had cancer at any point in my life, but I don't have cancer now.

In this case the present perfect talks about a past state.

If I have cancer now I would say: "I have cancer". Or "I have had cancer for three years".

That doesn't seem to apply to "I have been ill" by itself, because "I have been ill"(without a duration) doesn't tell us if someone is still ill or has recovered. What is the difference?

Why doesn't "have been" in this case refer to a past state?

If I am ill now, I would say: "I am ill". Or "I have been ill for two weeks".

So how come "I have had cancer" means I don't have cancer now, but "I have been ill" doesn't mean I am not ill anymore?

Could someone explain? They are both present perfect.

Comment: Because “had” is not the same as “been” and meaning depends on context.

Comment: Could you explain your answer, because I know "had" and "been"are not the same, but in my examples they are both present perfect. I think my examples are clear. I just don't understand.

Comment: Why does “I have had sushi” mean something different from “I have been sushi”? Different words often have different meanings.

Comment: I find your answer confusing, sorry.

Comment: It’s not an answer. Why do you think there is a reason other than “have had” means something different from “have been” because they are different words used to communicate different concepts? You might as well ask why does blue mean the color of the sky but green means the color of the grass.

Comment: That is not what I mean, I mean the use of present perfect in one case means it is in the past, but not necessarily in the other case.

Comment: Because “have been” means something different from “have had”. “I have had second thoughts and will be canceling my trip.” “I have been having second thoughts and I might cancel my trip.” There’s no reason that the tense of a verb has to force a particular meaning in English. Context always matters.